# MYSQL query to handle null value in a pair of values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose that we have the following database:

```
First_Id    Second_Id     Name
null        1             Durant
null        1             Kobe
1           2             Lebron
2           2             Dwight
1           3             Dirk
```

we want to extract rows in the way that two columns make some specific pairs like :

```
(1,2),(1,3)
```

so the answer would be equal to :

```
First_Id    Second_Id     Name
1           2             Lebron
1           3             Dirk
```

this can be using the following query :

```
SELECT *
FROM PLAYERS
WHERE (First_Id, Second_Id) IN (VALUES (1,2), (1,3))
```

what i want to do is to find those rows where the `First_Id` is `null`, how can i do it?

```
SELECT *
FROM PLAYERS
WHERE (First_Id, Second_Id) IN (VALUES (null,1),(1,2), (1,3))
```

the desired output is :

```
First_Id    Second_Id     Name
null        1             Durant
null        1             Kobe
1           2             Lebron
1           3             Dirk
```

Comment: `where First_Id is null`!

Comment: @jarlh this can make wrong answers, because `null` is a paired with `1`

Comment: `VALUES` does not work in MySQL. Are you using MySQL or is that a typo?

Comment: _"i want to do is to find those rows where the First_Id is null, how can i do it?"_ You probably missed the word _also_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use directly the equal and logicals operators. In the specific case it is more simple than what you are trying to do:

```
SELECT *
FROM PLAYERS
WHERE (First_Id is null and Second_Id = 1) 
   OR (First_Id = 1 and Second_Id = 2)
   OR (First_Id = 1 and Second_Id = 3)
```

Comment: It's working, but i was thinking to do it in an easier way, it's like a brute force attack to this problem :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
SELECT *
FROM PLAYERS
WHERE (First_Id, Second_Id) IN ((1,2), (1,3)) or (First_Id is null and Second_Id=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

That IN criteria looking for tupples doesn't consider the null values.

But those null's can be coalesced to another value. For example by 0, to look for the (0,1) tupple to get the null's:

```
SELECT *
FROM PLAYERS
WHERE (COALESCE(First_Id,0), Second_Id) IN ((0,1),(1,2),(1,3));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
from Players
where (First_Id in (1) or First_Id is Null )
and Second_Id in (1,2,3)
```

Try this.